# use voice command to open app and send input

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I am aware of the `open youtube` voice command in android, for opening youtube. but before that we have to give `ok google` command also.

But i need to know is there any way by which i dont have to say `ok google` and directly i say `Hi myapp, call amrit` where `myapp` is name of app that will be invoke and `call amrit` is argument for the app, and later using those it will do the necessary processing.

I have searched many website and blogs on internet, but no luck! Need to know is something like this is possible?